# Change barcode scan beep volume for motorola devices

Tags: c#, compact-framework, motorola-emdk

I am developing some .net applications with c# for various Motorola devices running Windows Mobile and Windows CE. These include the MC9190 and the WT41N0. On these two models, it beeps very loudly when a barcode is scanned. Is there anyway using the Motorola emdk or by changing a registry setting to make the beep quieter without turning the beep off altogether.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this works for all Motorola devices, but you could try including `Symbol.Audio` and:

```
using Symbol.Audio;
...
using (StandardAudio audio = new StandardAudio(Device.AvailableDevices[0]))
{
    audio.BeeperVolume = 1;
}
```

You can inspect the `audio.BeeperVolumeLevels` property to see what the maximum volume level is.

Answer (score 1):

In Symbol scanner terminology this is called "feedback", and by default it's the local feedback setting that gets in the way of properly managing the audio.

In your application, after you create the reader, the following settings control it:

```
    _BarcodeReader.Parameters.Feedback.Success.BeepFrequency = 2000
    _BarcodeReader.Parameters.Feedback.Success.BeepTime = 20
```

_BarcodeReader being the reader object.  I set it to lower frequency for a shorter time above.

If you need to eliminate the beeping altogether:

```
_BarcodeReader.Parameters.Feedback.Success.BeepTime = 0
```

You may want to add your own wave file:

```
_BarcodeReader.Parameters.Feedback.Success.WaveFile = "decode.wav"
```

This is also the case with the DataWedge software that ships with MC9xxx and MC3xxx series. If you're using DataWedge, look for "local feedback" under the feedback menu, from Scanner,  under Basic configuration.

The scan audio can only be managed from the feedback settings, volume control and other methods have no effect. It seems Zebra (previously Motorola) used high-volume default for loud  industrial settings, wish they had considered a better way to configure though.

Comment: For our MC32N0 this worked (thank you @can.do !! Our customers were going crazy with that loud beep!), and the method I called from my VS2008 CF3.5 C# application was a little different, but basically the same: `barcode21.Config.ScanParameters.BeepTime = 0;`

Comment: And for a "mellow" sound, I added this setting: `barcode21.Config.ScanParameters.BeepFrequency = 1000`

Comment: Glad that worked for you.   We now use a data-file and menu options for various configurations for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I put a piece of Scotch tape over the speaker on mine.

The tape dampens most of the noise while I am testing here at my desk, but it is simple to remove so they can hear it out on the floor.

Outside or on our production floor, they need the loud noise.

If that doesn't work for you, in the Settings on our Datalogic Falcons, there is a Decoding application. One of the inputs there is called Audio and enables someone to turn down the volume.

Since I don't have the SDK for the Datalogic Falcon, I can only post a low resolution cell phone clip. Hope this helps.

[image: Cell Phone Clip]

Answer (score 0):

There is a configuration utility for motorola devices. It is a single exe file you can put on your device and then you can adjust several settings and also the beeper volume. I had a look on support.symbol.com but I didn't found it. I think you can get it from your vendor-support.

Answer (score 0):

In our situation with a Motorola MC9590 device using telnet sessions, the volume control on the left-side of the device needs to be adjusted down prior to signing into the telnet session.  The volume level remains at the established setting once the user signs into their telnet session.

Comment: The original question seems to be asking for a software fix, not a hardware/user workaround.

Answer (score 0):

The volume can be controlled by pressing the blue function key and then the H or M key. The display brightness can be controlled by pressing the blue function key and then the D or I key.

Answer (score -1):

the way I made it silence was : *go to control panel* -> *All control panel items* -> *Devices and Printers*. find the `Symbol bar code` and **right click** and *select*  `Keyboard settings`, on the `speed box` you will see a `Repeat delay icon` just **drag** that all the way to the *left* and the sound should go away.

Comment: This is a question regarding development work I assume. You can't technically do that on the client devices except asking the users to do that themselves.